# How to invoke Android ChangeListener upon manual toggle() of switch it listens to?

Tags: java, android, xml, switch-statement, listener

I've got a switch to which I set a listener like this:

```
mySwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CustomOnCheckedChangeListener(findViewById(R.id.my_view)));
```

The CustomOnCheckedChangeListener starts an animation to show another field (the R.id.my_view, which is hidden by default because I set the android:layout_height="0dp" in the xml). The custom listener looks like this:

```
public class CustomOnCheckedChangeListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {
    private final View[] mViews;

    public CustomOnCheckedChangeListener(View... views) {
        mViews = views;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        for (View v : mViews) {
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) v;
            if (isChecked) {
                Animation anim = expand(layout, true);
                layout.startAnimation(anim);
            } else {
                Animation anim = expand(layout, false);
                layout.startAnimation(anim);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This all works like a charm. I now want to do something different though. When I receive an id I need to set the switch to "On" to show the corresponding view. So I toggle the switch as follows:

```
mySwitch.toggle();
```

Although this does toggle the switch to On, it doesn't invoke the animation that expands the view.

Would anybody know how I can invoke this animation so that it shows the view on start of the screen?